# Is it possible to extrude these faces into a clean mesh?

Tags: modeling

I have these faces, and I want to extrude them.
[image]
The extrusion tool creates something that looks great on the outside, but creates an absolute disaster on the inside.
[image]

Trying to selectively delete the crap on the inside just rips holes out of the face, so that doesn't work. Mesh cleaning services like Netfabb do not work. I'm tempted to take pics of the visually pleasing mesh and feed it into photogrammetry software, please help.

Comment: select just the vertices on the edges of the object and extrude those, no need to extrude eyes, nose and other parts.

Comment: Why does the inside matter? Isn't it good enough that the outside looks fine?

Comment: I'm trying to make a watertight mesh for 3D printing

Comment: What if you duplicate the faces (shift+D), right click to snap them back into place, and then extrude? You should then be able to delete the internal geometry without leaving holes.

Comment: do you have any reason to keep it squashed on the Y axis? Why don't you scale it on the Y axis first?